# textbox validation for number and required in repeating mode angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Please refer below link

https://plnkr.co/edit/9HbLMBUw0Q6mj7oyCahP?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.NDCarray = [{val: ''}];

$scope.NDCadd = function() {
    $scope.NDCarray.unshift(
        {val: ''}
    );
};
$scope.data = angular.copy($scope.NDCarray);
$scope.NDCcancel=function(){debugger
  $scope.NDCarray=$scope.data;
}


$scope.NDCdelete = function(index) {
  if(index != $scope.NDCarray.length -1){
    $scope.NDCarray.splice(index, 1);
  }
};
});
```

It contains the textbox with add button. I have added validation for number and required field, it is working fine. but when i click add button it will create another textbox with entered value that time it showing the validation message for all the textboxes , i don't want to show validation message for all the textboxes. need to show validation for corresponding textbox only. that means when i enter something wrong in second textbox it is showing message to that textbox only.refer below screenshot.

[image]

validation message displaying for all textboxes.that should display for only one textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/f4kAdZSIsxWECd0i8LDT?p=preview

Your problem is in your HTML, to get independant fields you must :

- Move outside the form of the ng-repeat
- Provide a dynamic name using $index on your fields, because name is what make each fields independant on the validation.

Here is the final HTML from the plnkr i didn't touch at all the javascript :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <form name="myForm">
    <div ng-repeat ="ndc in NDCarray">
    <div class="col-sm-4 type7" style="font-size:14px;">
        <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">NDC9</div>

  <label>Number:
    <input type="number"  ng-model="ndc.value"
           min="0" max="99" name="{{'input_'+$index}}" required>
 </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$dirty && myForm.input.$error.required">
      Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.number">
      Not valid number!</span>
  </div>
  <tt>value = {{example.value}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm['input_{{$index}}'].$valid = {{myForm['input_'+$index].$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm['input_{{$index}}'].$error = {{myForm['input_'+$index].$error}}</tt><br/>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 type7 " style="font-size:14px;">
        <div style="padding-top:20px; display:block"> 
            <span class="red" id="delete" ng-class="{'disabled' : 'true'}" ng-click="NDCdelete($index)">Delete</span> &nbsp; 
            <span>Cancel </span> &nbsp;  
            <span id="addRow" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="NDCadd()">Add </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>

   </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: it is not showing the validation message for required and invalid number

Comment: just change ther myForm.input to myForm['input_'+$index] everytimes and it's working. Note : you won't see the invalid number error because the field force to have a number, however you forget to handle `min` & `max` validation errors, They will be under `myForm['input_'+$index].$error.min` & `myForm['input_'+$index].$error.max`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of changes:

1. If you add "track by $index" to your ng-repeat it will make each group of elements unique so that you don't have to worry about deriving unique names for elements.
2. Your validation on the number (myForm.ndcValue.$error.number) didn't work so I changed it to myForm.ndcValue.$error.max || myForm.ndcValue.$error.min
3. Also, you can throw an ng-form attribute directly on the div with your ng-repeat.

**Like this:**

```
  <div ng-repeat="ndc in NDCarray track by $index" ng-form="myForm">
    <div class="col-sm-4 type7" style="font-size:14px;">
      <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">NDC9</div>

      <label>Number:
        <input type="number" ng-model="ndc.value" min="0" max="99" name="ndcValue" required>
      </label>
      <div role="alert">
       <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.ndcValue.$dirty && myForm.ndcValue.$error.required">
       Required!</span>
       <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.ndcValue.$error.max || myForm.ndcValue.$error.min">
       Not valid number!</span>
      </div>
      <tt>value = {{example.value}}</tt>
      <br/>
      <tt>myForm.ndcValue.$valid = {{myForm.ndcValue.$valid}}</tt>
      <br/>
      <tt>myForm.ndcValue.$error = {{myForm.ndcValue.$error}}</tt>
      <br/>

    </div>
```

Here's the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vTDOO9aUmkqHu1KRkZfR?p=preview).

I changed the input element name from "input" to "ndcValue" to be less confusing.

Comment: it is not showing the validation message for invalid number

Comment: You have a min=0 and max=99 so I just set the validation for anything that falls outside of that range.  What other validation were you looking for?

Comment: when i  type charcaters apart from numeric it should show "not valid number"

Comment: In your plunker no valiation message is coming. even required field too

Comment: You can set the validation to whatever you want, including what you originally had (myForm.ndcValue.$error.number)

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right plunker?  I'm getting the messages.

Comment: I think you're looking at the previous fork from another contributor.

Comment: Yes i am seeing your plunkr only it is not showing validation message. could you please check the link again

Comment: Enter 999.  Do you see the message then?  I just did.